# Jmeter SSRS reports testing

Tags: asp.net, performance, testing, reporting-services, jmeter

I have a aspx webpage which is integrated with SSRS reports.I want to perform a performance test using Jmeter,I used the Jmeter HTTP(S) script recorder for the same.It was seen that the response data captured by Jmeter does not the show the report data as the response tough the POST was successfull.
Just wanted to know if there any other method to test the SSRS reports integrated with aspx pages.

In the above context the jmeter test is intended to test the response time of reports.

Kindly help,Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem like this?

> Browser settings prevent scripts from running on this report. To view this report without scripts, click here. Report Viewer Configuration Error
>   The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file.....

If yes, I hope this solution will help you.

My Error above was produced by JMeter path like below:

```
.../Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/myReportPath/MyReport&rs:Command=Render&rs:ParameterLanguage=en-US&....
```

Then I changed my JMeter path with this:

```
...?/myReportPath/myReport&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0&rc:LinkTarget=_top&rc:Javascript=false&rc:Toolbar=false&rs:ParameterLanguage=en-US&....
```

It solved my problem. My JMeter script got the correct response from the server.  JMeter got the report correctly.